# Error in posting data using angular in MEAN stack

Tags: angular, http-post, httprequest, mean-stack

When i use GET and POST methods on port 4200 using Postman, all are working fine. But in the browser when i submit the form it shows ***HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", url: "http://localhost:3000/employees/undefined", ok: false, …}***

Here i have included only the relevant parts of the code...

model.ts

```
 export class Employee {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    position: string;
    office: string;
    salary: number;
}
```

serivice.ts

```
    export class EmployeeService {

  selectedEmployee: Employee;
  employees: Employee[];

  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/employees';

  constructor( private http: HttpClient  ) { }

  postEmployee(emp: Employee):  Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http.post<Employee>(this.baseURL, emp);
  }

  getEmployeeList() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL);
  }

  putEmployee(emp: Employee) {
    return this.http.put(this.baseURL + `/${emp._id}`, emp);
  }

  deleteEmployee(_id: string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.baseURL + `/${_id}`);
  }
}
```

component.html

```
            <form #employeeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeForm)">

              <!-- _Id -->
              <input type="hidden" name="_id" #_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService?.selectedEmployee._id">

              <!-- name -->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService?.selectedEmployee.name" placeholder="Enter full name" required>
                  <label>Name :
                    <label class="red-text">*</label>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
                <button class="btn btn-custom right" type="submit" [disabled]="!employeeForm.valid">Submit</button>
```

component.ts

```
    export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( public employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.resetForm();
     this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = new Employee ();
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form) {
      form.reset();
      this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = {
        _id: '',
        name: '',
        position: '',
        office: '',
        salary: null
      };
    }
  }


  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value._id === '') {
      this.employeeService.postEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        M.toast({ html: 'Saved successfully', classes: 'rounded' });
      });
    } else {
      this.employeeService.putEmployee(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.refreshEmployeeList();
        M.toast({ html: 'Updated successfully', classes: 'rounded' });
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Assuming port 4200 is the angular app running in ng-serve. Also assuming port 3000 is where your nodejs server is running. Have you tested postman requests to your nodejs server on port 3000?

Comment: found the answer just an hour ago...  `if (form.value._id === '') ` this is the problem...